# How to mock a final new instance of RestTemplate using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
Component
public class MyService {
  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  public void myMethod(){
      

    ------- codes to test above it------ 
     
     HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(objectMapper
          .writeValueAsString(message), httpHeaders);
      String response = restTemplate
          .postForObject(getUrl(), httpEntity, String.class);

  }

}
```

I have tried @Spy but it's not working

```
@InjectMocks
  private MyService myService;
  
  @Spy
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;


 when(restTemplate.postForObject(
    getUrl(),
    httpEntity,
    String.class
)).thenReturn(getResponse());
```

Comment: Is this Spring?

Comment: You can write a protected constructor for MyService which takes a RestTemplate parameter.

Comment: Yes it's in spring

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spy:

```
@Test
void test(){
    MyService myService = Mockito.spy(MyService.class);
    myService.myMethod();
}
```

In this way, you get the instance of RestTemplate.

I personally prefer receiving RestTemplate as a dependency which makes it easy to mock.

for eg:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

And in your test

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) //junit4
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) //junit 5
public class MyServiceTest {

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private MyService myService;

@Test
void test(){
    when(restTemplate.postForObject(
            getUrl(),
            httpEntity,
            String.class
    )).thenReturn(getResponse());
    //do whatever you like
   }

}
```

Comment: I want to mock postForObject method not invoke the actual method

Comment: You are trying to test myMethod(), didn't you?

Comment: oh missed the detail I want to test the code above it not invoke the actual http call,edited my code

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-test provides a nice way to mock beans via [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) and [SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) annotations.

Try using `@SpyBean` instead of `@Spy` and `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`.

```java
@MockBean
private RestTemplate restTemplate
```

In this case no `@InjectMocks` required.